# Bright out north Idaho

Tags: night-sky, brightness

It is Oct 9th 10;30- 11:00 pm. I'm in Northern Idaho and it is as bright as it would be with a full moon (or brighter). The moon is going to be new in a few days and the sliver as it is won't be out for hours. I live in my motorhome right now and it is usually so dark I need a flashlight to walk 10ft to my car. It is really weird. Kind of eerie. Any reason why? Thank you

Comment: It's not aurora,  no significant space weather right now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as it lacks prior research.

Comment: @WarpPrime there is no close reason in Stack Exchange for "lacking prior research". The only function that closing provides is answer blocking. There is no reason to prevent anyone in the community from posting an answer here. The suggested action if a question is felt to lack prior research is the down vote. i.stack.imgur.com/qEPOw.png not the answer-preventing close vote.